# Have dependengy jar automatically add to STS project when added as dependency in build.gradle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I created a Spring Boot application at https://start.spring.io.

The dependencies I added at the time all exist. Now that I'm developing the app in STS I have to add dependencies to build.gradle from time to time. How can I get the relevant jars to be added to the project without manually downloading them and adding them through `Configure Build Path...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component in Eclipse that supports Gradle is called [Buildship](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship). To add an new dependency you should modify your `build.gradle` file and add the dependency in the `dependencies {}` block. You can then right-click the project and select `Gradle -> Refresh Gradle Project` as described [here](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2018/february/buildship.php). This will download the dependency (and all of its dependencies) and then update the classpath of the project.